Toy proof assistants with very small codebases
I am interested in toy proof assistants with very small codebases (a single file would be ideal) that are reasonably easy to read, understand, and poke.
Smallness is more important here than any other consideration, such as ease of use or protecting you from making illegal API calls and tainting the state of the prover.
What are some examples of such assistants?

What follows is my motivation for asking this question in the first place
My longer-term goal is to understand the vanilla Calculus of Constructions and after that fancier stuff like inductive types, co-inductive types, or self types.
I tried and failed to formalize the vanilla Calculus of Constructions yesterday, first in Coq and then in Prolog. So today I tried something easy and implemented a toy prover for the implication-only fragment of intuitionistic propositional logic as a Python library. Attached as Appendix A.
Python ended up being a reasonable host language for a type system explorer, since it gives control over pretty printing, although it does not protect you in any way from making illegal API calls.
Anyway, the process of writing this was interesting enough that I was wondering if there were real examples of simple toy provers with expressive type systems or different types of APIs (like support for backward reasoning or some automated tactics).
Also, to be clear, the library is trivial. I'm kind of reluctant to even post it. But it does demonstrate that type of thing that I'm looking for real examples of.
Appendix A
import collections
import doctest
import unittest


"""
This is a simple explorer for the intuitionistic propositional calculus.

It is a toy.

If you start out with a true term, then every method that is called on it
will also be true (i.e. every method is monotonic with respect to the truth
value of the receiver.)
"""


# Complaints
#
# 1) I really want a reasonable OrderedSet, but Python doesn't have it in its standard library.
#    So in a few places I cast back and forth between list and set in the implementation of term.
#
# 2) Sorting is weird.


class HypothesisNotFound(Exception):
    pass


class TopmostConnectiveNotImplication(Exception):
    pass


class HypothesesDoNotMatch(Exception):
    pass


class I(collections.namedtuple("IBase", "prem conc")):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"I({repr(self.prem)}, {repr(self.conc)})"

    def __str__(self):
        """
        >>> str(I("A", I("B", "C")))
        '(A) → (B) → C'
        """
        return f"({str(self.prem)}) → {str(self.conc)}"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Term):
            return other == self
        return super().__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(("I", self.prem, self.conc))


def f(x):
    """Key func for the environment"""
    if isinstance(x, I):
        return (1, x)
    return (0, x)


def sort(xs):
    return sorted(xs, key=f)


class Term:
    def __init__(self, item, env=None):
        """Create a new term in IPC with a conclusion (item) and premises (env)
        >>> Term(env={"A"}, item="X")
        Term('X', ['A'])
        """
        self.env = set(env) if env else set()
        self.item = item

    def __repr__(self):
        """Show an IPC term in Python syntax."""
        if self.env:
            return f"Term({repr(self.item)}, {repr(sort(self.env))})"
        else:
            return f"Term({repr(self.item)})"

    def __str__(self):
        """Show an IPC term in friendly syntax.
        >>> str(Term('X', {'A'}))
        "{'A'} ⊢ X"
        """
        return f"{str(self.env)} ⊢ {str(self.item)}"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, I):
            other = Term(other)
        return self.env == other.env and self.item == other.item

    def copy(self):
        """copy a Term
        >>> s = Term('X', ['A'])
        >>> s.copy().extend(['B'])
        Term('X', ['A', 'B'])
        >>> s
        Term('X', ['A'])
        """
        return Term(self.item, self.env.copy())

    def extend(self, hypotheses):
        """Destructively add new hypotheses to the environment. Return self for method chaining.

        >>> Term("X", {"A"}).extend(["B"])
        Term('X', ['A', 'B'])
        """
        self.env.update(hypotheses)
        return self

    def ii(self, hypothesis):
        """Implication introduction. Take a hypothesis, remove it from the environment and add it to the item. Destructive.

        >>> Term("X", {"A"}).ii("A")
        Term(I('A', 'X'))
        """
        try:
            self.env.remove(hypothesis)
        except KeyError:
            raise HypothesisNotFound(f"hypothesis {hypothesis} not found")
        self.item = I(hypothesis, self.item)
        return self

    def ie(self):
        """Implication elimination. Remove the topmost implication from the item. Destructive.

        >>> Term(I('A', 'X')).ie()
        Term('X', ['A'])
        """
        if not isinstance(self.item, I):
            raise TopmostConnectiveNotImplication(
                f"{self.item} not headed by implication"
            )
        head = self.item.prem
        self.item = self.item.conc
        self.env.add(head)
        return self

    def cut(self, other):
        """Cut rule, but more like modus ponens.

        Γ ⊢ A    Δ, A ⊢ B
        -----------------       is traditional cut
           Γ, Δ ⊢ B

        Γ ⊢ A    Δ ⊢ A → B
        ------------------      is our cut
           Γ, Δ ⊢ B

        Doing it this way means that the output context of the rule is the union
        of the input contexts, which is slightly simpler.

        With implication introduction and elimination, these rules are equivalent.

        >>> Term(env={"X"}, item="A").cut(Term(env={"Y"}, item=I("A", "B")))
        Term('B', ['X', 'Y'])

        >>> Term(env={"X"}, item="A").cut(Term(env={"A", "Y"}, item=I("A", "B")))
        Term('B', ['A', 'X', 'Y'])

        """
        if not isinstance(other.item, I):
            raise TopmostConnectiveNotImplication(
                f"{other.item} not headed by implication"
            )
        if self.item != other.item.prem:
            raise HypothesesDoNotMatch(
                f"{self.item} does not match {other.item.prem}"
            )
        self.item = other.item.conc
        self.extend(other.env)
        return self


def make_id(item, rest=None):
    """
    >>> make_id("A")
    Term('A', ['A'])
    """
    rest = set(rest or [])
    rest.update(item)
    return Term(item, rest)


class TermTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_prove_axiom1(self):
        s = make_id("A", "A")
        s.extend("B")
        s.ii("B")
        s.ii("A")
        self.assertEqual(s, Term(I("A", I("B", "A"))))

    def test_make_complex_term(self):
        Term(I("A", "B"), [I("X", "Y"), I("Y", "Z")])

    def test_order(self):
        sort([I("X", "Y"), I("A", "B")])
        sort(["A", I("A", "B")])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
    unittest.main()
```


Two answers that come to mind are Pie from the little typer and Andrej Bauer's toy implementation of dependent type theory

Also, many implementations of Metamath checkers can be quite small.  Metamath isn't a type theory, but can be used to implement type theories like Higher-Order Logic and Lean's kernel (the latter is in MM0, a variation of metamath, but is quite readable as a reference).

The link to my blog post is essentially obsolete (I should update the blog post to say so), my latest version of a small type theory checker is at https://github.com/andrejbauer/spartan-type-theory

In CoC, the impredicative universe of props is very complicated, and it is usually ok to just skip it.

HOL Light's kernel is tiny, just to give something simpler to study.

@ice1000 If you try to build semantics or meta-theoretic proofs, indeed impredicativity can bite hard, but I don't think it has such an impact on complexity of the type theory. It basically only makes the rules for universe levels slightly more involved, but nothing crazy. Although I agree it can be left out for a "spartan" type theory.

@AndrejBauer those sound like quality answers to me!

Python's set, in the most recent versions, is now defined as an ordered set. Previous versions had it ordered, but not defined to be ordered, then it was unordered, but as that broke programs, they defined it as ordered.

@prosfilaes I believe that is true of dictionaries but not of sets. The dictionary implementation mentions a key order (it's the order of dk_entries). The set implementation does not have an intrinsic order. You can also see it by evaluating list(set([3, 2, 1, 10])) which produces [10, 1, 2, 3], which is neither the sorted order nor the insertion order.

Also my comment isn't very good. I just wanted a deterministic, easy to predict repr function that listed the items in sorted order because I'm using doctests everywhere to keep the code size down. Also Term is named badly. That class is really more of a type than a term. There are many things wrong with my toy prover.

Here are some that I am aware of:

A Tutorial Implementation of a Dependently Typed Lambda Calculus by Andres Löh, Conor McBride and Wouter Swierstra, implemented in Haskell, has an accompanying tutorial paper.

Elaboration zoo by Andras Kovacs has examples ranging from basic to advanced techniques. It is implemented in Haskell and good for learning how to do things the Right Way.

Spartan type theory is a very basic implementation of a type theory checker, implemented in OCaml. It also shows how to implement the practical things, such as source-code locations, pretty-printing, and command-line options.



Logic and Computation Intertwined (from Ragde’s flâneries) has you build a rudimentary proof assistant in Racket. I think it meets your goals of being small and easy to play with.
Here’s a smattering of my code from working through it, for example.

mmverify.py is not a toy, but it is very small. It verifies metamath programs and is written as a single Python file. It only imports from the standard library.
https://github.com/david-a-wheeler/mmverify.py/blob/ee80f30ea8e2492cc4cc5e9b5add05ce6ea00932/mmverify.py
